# What is compactness for a deductive system?

Tags: logic, compactness, computer-science, formal-systems

In [Herre & Schroeder-Heister's "Formal Languages and Systems"](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/%7Esancheg/EE_UCU2006_thesis/biblio/Formal%20Languages%20and%20Systems%20(RoutledgeFLS1995).pdf), on p6,

> It (i.e. a consequential operation) is called a deductive system, if the consequences of a set X can be
> obtained from a ﬁnite subset of X, i.e., if in addition to the three conditions mentioned,
> $$C(X) ⊆ \cup \text{ $\{C(Y ) : Y ⊆ X$, $Y$ ﬁnite $\}$ (compactness)}$$

Is it correct that in set theory, union $\cup$ is defined between finitely many sets, and not for infinitely many sets (uncountably many sets in particular)?

Does compactness mean that any $X$ has  finitely many finite subsets $Y_i$'s, s.t. $C(X) \subseteq \cup_i C(Y_i)$?

Thanks.

p.s. Could you recommend other references that provides definitions of a consequence operator being  inclusive, idemponent, monotonic,  and compact, besides Herre's? Herre's is the only source I have seen these concepts.

Comment: No, union is defined for arbitrary collections of sets: $$\bigcup\mathscr{X}=\{x:\exists X\in\mathscr{X}\,(x\in X)\}\;.$$ There is no implication that $X$ has only finitely many subsets. Indeed, were that the case, $X$ would be finite, and that definition would just say that $C(X)=C(X)$.

Comment: Informally, compactness just means that one never needs infinitely many premises in a proof: If the conclusion is derivable, finitely many premises will suffice; if it can't be derived form finitely many premises, infinitely many won't help either.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it correct that in set theory, union $\cup$ is defined between finitely many sets, and not for infinitely many sets (uncountably many sets in particular)?

No, there is no such restriction. The notation being used here is that if $X$ is a (arbitrary) collection of sets $\cup X$ is the union of all the sets in that collection, i.e. the collection of all elements of elements of $X.$

> Does compactness mean that any $X$ has  finitely many finite subsets $Y_i$'s, s.t. $C(X) \subseteq \cup_i C(Y_i)$?

No, it just means that any consequence of $X$ is also the consequence of some finite subset of $X.$ It will only sometimes be the case that there is some fixed finite subset of $X$ such that all consequences of $X$ are consequences of that subset. (Or that there is some fixed finite collection of finite subsets such that all consequences of $X$ are consequences of one of these subsets.)

> p.s. Could you recommend other references that provides definitions of a consequence operator being inclusive, idemponent, monotonic, and compact, besides Herre's? Herre's is the only source I have seen these concepts.

Sorry, don't know of any.